# Translate to linq query

Tags: sql-server, linq

Please help me translate this code to linq query.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT dbo.Port.PortId, dbo.Port.Name
    FROM  dbo.Port INNER JOIN
          dbo.Charge ON dbo.Port.PortId = dbo.Charge.PortId
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
var q = (from tbl in yourContext.Port 
join tbl1 in yourContext.Charge on tbl.PortId = tbl1.PortId
select tbl).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this (in lambda form):

```
var query = youContext.Port                 //left table - outer
            .Join (youContext.Charge,       //right table - inner
                   p => p.PortId,           //left table outer key selector
                   c => c.PortId,           //right table inner key selector
                   (x, y) => new {x})       //result of join
            .Select(x => new {x.PortId,
                              x.Name})      //finish selection
            .Distinct();                    //remove re-entry
```